# Network stops converging after reaching a particular accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, backpropagation

After completing this course, I decided to implement a deep neural network from scratch to deepen my understanding but on training the network the accuracy steadily increases until it reaches 35% and then starts decreasing. Here is the backprop algorithm I've implemented.

I've set the learning rate to 0.001. I've tested upto epoch number 500. The accuracy slowly increases which suggests that backprop is correct but then it stops and starts decreasing. I think there might still be a bug in the backward pass but I cannot find it.
Training accuracy of each epoch can be found here =>https://pastebin.com/bfQc6B2F

```
        #FORWARD PROP
        z2 = self.parameters['W1'].dot(inpt)+self.parameters['b1']
        a2 = relu(z2)
        z3 = self.parameters['W2'].dot(a2)+self.parameters['b2']
        man_output = softmax(z3,self)

        #BACKPROP
        sigma3 = prediction-mappings
        sigma2 = self.parameters['W2'].T.dot(sigma3)* reluGrad(a2)
        dW2 = (1/m)*sigma3.dot(a2.T)
        db2 = (1/m)*np.sum(sigma3,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        dW1 = (1/m)*sigma2.dot(inpt.T)
        db1 = (1/m)*np.sum(sigma2,axis=1,keepdims=True)
        self.grads={'dW1':dW1,'db1':db1,'dW2':dW2,'db2':db2}

        #UPDATE PARAMETERS
        for l in range(int(len(self.parameters)/2)):
            self.parameters['W'+str(l+1)] = self.parameters['W'+str(l+1)] -alpha*self.grads['dW'+str(l+1)]
            self.parameters['b'+str(l+1)] = self.parameters['b'+str(l+1)] -alpha*self.grads['db'+str(l+1)]
```

Comment: I don't know about your problem, but you should set a higher learning rate at the begining, maybe 0.01, and then decrease it when your accuracy not change so much. 500 epoch is too much, and that's why your accuracy slowly increases !!
Also, consider to do mini batch when training, instead of using all the dataset in a forward pass). Maybe it could improve your accuracy, but maybe not.